# Python TypeError while converting JSON

Tags: python, json, openweathermap

I have some code here, for my Slack Bot:

```
import pyowm

owm.set_API_key('Key Here')
observation = owm.weather_at_id(4744326)
w = observation.get_weather()
jsondata= w.get_temperature('fahrenheit') # Here is our JSON Data. 
response = (json.loads(jsondata))
print(response)
```

The JSON I'm trying to convert is:

```
{"temp": 47.05, "temp_max": 50.0, "temp_min": 42.8, "temp_kf": null}
```

When i run this, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Any tips?

Comment: it would seem that `jsondata` is already a dictionary so there is no need to parse it using the `json` library

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre] including the full error message with traceback. (In this case, that would mean posting the output of `w.get_temperature('fahrenheit')`.)

Comment: The [docs](https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.weatherapi25.html?highlight=get_temperature#pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather.get_temperature) are pretty clear that `get_temperature` returns a `dict`, not raw json.

Comment: @aws_apprentice Based on your response, i tried `response = ("The current temperature (Fahrenheit) is:",jsondata[1])` and i get: `Exception has occurred: KeyErrorFile "D:\my codes\2022bot.py", line 65, in handle_command
    response = ("The current temperature (Fahrenheit) is:",jsondata[1])
  File "D:\my codes\2022bot.py", line 85, in <module>
    handle_command(command, channel)`

Comment: the issue in your attempt is that `1` is not a valid key in the dictionary, perhaps you might need to revisit how to access elements in a dictionary?

Comment: ok ow, no need to throw shade like that @aws_apprentice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does return as a dictionary, I was just being stupid and calling it wrong.